# Strange behaviour on safari on ios. Too complicated to explain here

Tags: ios, html, safari

I've been asked by a friend to fix a strange problem, that I admit it, I can't understand.

The website is here: www.fabrizionannini.com, open it on your favourite browser.
Everything works (there are some little quirks but it works).

Now get your ipad/iphone/ipod and open the page, go to videos. You now can't click any of the submenus that pops up! The z-indexes are ok, in fact the menu is still on top of the video, you can't simply click on it! I'm really frustated becasue I don't understand the problem.

I hope some of you have encountered a similar issue and can help me understand the problem..

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i tested on the ipod and the video sublinks work perfectly. what ios version are you running and what device?

i tested it on ipod 4g firmware 4.2.1

can you post a screenshot of the area your having a problem with?